# Issue with FileMaker Pro Buttons and Creating New Records

Tags: filemaker

I'm tasked with creating a layout that allows users to create a new order. I've written script for this task, however, I can't get it to account for buttons. Neither the "Add_Order_Line" or "Delete_Order_Line" work. Moreover, I'm not sure how to configure a process that saves the entire record (and subsequent related records) and confirms with the user that the order has been saved. I've attached screenshots of my work

Any input is greatly appreciated!

[image: Layout]
[image: New Order Script]
[image: Create New Order Line]
[image: Delete Order Line]
[image: Data Relationships]

Comment: StackOverflow is purely a question-and-answer site. I suggest you ask this at one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform where you can get more detailed help, including example files.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create a record in the portal.
1). easy way, is to go into the relationship graph and tick the Create records from this relation ship. This will give you an empty row, and once you enter something in a field it is created.
2). The other is to copy the ID of the main record and then go to the child layout and create a new record, fill in the data along with the ID of that main record. That is the link. once done your should see the row back in that first layout.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In the relationship graph make sure that you have allow creation of records in this table checked[UI of where the setting is]. This script outlines what's required and the rest you should be able to manage.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v9LO.png)

Comment: If the relationship is allowed to create related records, then there should be no need to for the script to store the primary key in a variable and set the foreign key field in the portal table. In fact, there should no need for a script at all; you could just fill out the necessary details directly in the portal.